# why does this C++ code print a after every line?

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {

  for (;;) {
    char ch ;
    if (cin.fail()) break;
    cin.read((char*)&ch, sizeof(unsigned char));
    cout<<hex<<(unsigned int)(unsigned char)ch<<endl;
    cin.clear();
  }   
}
```

Why does this code always print `a` after every line? I just used any `char` as standard input. **Added**: I am trying to read unformatted input with `read`.

Comment: What is it *supposed* to print?

Comment: I used any char for standard input

Comment: i'm curious why you did `(char*)&ch`

Comment: I used the example in the textbook and it used (char*)&ch I am not sure why. I am about to add that question as well but retracted it, because I don't want to ask too much in one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a` that you see is simply the hex value of the `'\n'` character at the end of the line of input.

If you don't want to see that character, simply wrap the output line in an `if` statement that checks for that character and doesn't bother to do any output when it's seen:

```
if (ch != '\n') {
    cout<<hex<<(unsigned int)(unsigned char)ch<<endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 Oh so basically all I have to do is remove endl from the code then.

Comment: Wait I am still getting a. So its probably the enter character and not the endl messing with me?

Answer (score 3):

This code is reading a character at a time and writing out the value of the character in hexadecimal.

What you might not be expecting is that the pressing Enter also sends a character, which is read by your call to `cin.read`.

The `a` is the hexadecimal value of that character. So if you type `hello` and press `Enter`, the following will result from the cout statements:

```
68
65
6c
6c
6f
a
```

If you stop displaying the value in hexadecimal, you'll notice that it prints `10` after each entry.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation but how do I stop this program from reading enter as a character as well?

Comment: Don't type it.  Or check whether ch == 10 before you print its code.

Comment: You'd want to add some logic to skip over that character. Try putting `if (ch == 0xA) continue;` on a new line between the `cin.read` and `cout`. This will cause the loop move on to the next iteration whenever the newline character is read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even know what you're trying to accomplish with this. Don't use `cin.read` to read a single character. This loop should look more like this:

```
char ch;
while (std::cin.get(ch)) {
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(ch) << std::endl;
}
```

As to why it prints something, are you sure it's not the character you're actually inputting?

Comment: I am using read so I can read unformatted input. Do you know a way around this so I get to keep using read?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you still tell me why there is an 'a' after every input?

Comment: Also I am still getting the same error, that is a after every input.

Comment: @Mark: Paste your input and output.

Answer (score 1):

GargantuChet has correctly explained why you get 'a's.

More generally, there are many other issues

```
1 for (;;)
2 {
3     char ch;
4     if (cin.fail()) break;
5     cin.read((char*)&ch, sizeof(unsigned char));
6     cout << hex << (unsigned int)(unsigned char)ch < <endl;
7     cin.clear();
8 }
```

On line 4, you see if `cin.fail()` is set, but with streams they will never start in a failed state - you have to attempt to do something for that to fail.  In other words, you should do the `read()` *then* have a look at `cin.fail()`.  In general, you should also use `gcount()` to check how many bytes could actually be read (e.g. despite asking for say 4 you might only get 2, which wouldn't be considered a failure), but here you're only requesting 1 character so it can be simpler.

Cleaning it up a bit but keeping the same basic approach:

```
1 for (char ch; cin.read(&ch, sizeof ch); )
2     cout << hex << (unsigned)(unsigned char)ch < <endl;
```

This works because `read()` returns a reference to `cin`, and evaluating the "truth" of `cin` is a shorthand for asking if the input it's performed so far has been error-free (more strictly, at least since the last `clear()` if you're using that).

Still, `std::istream` - of which `std::cin` is an instance - also has a function designed for getting characters, allowing the loop to be simplified to:

```
for (char ch; std::cin.get(ch); )
    ...
```

**Aside**

Remember that a `for( ; ; )` control statement has three parts:

- the initialisation code on the left which can also create new variables
- the test: this happens *before* the 1st and every subsequent execution of the loop's statement(s)
- code to be executed only *after* the each execution of the statement(s) and before repeating the test.

Because of this, tests like `std::cin.get(ch)` are called and evaluated for success as a condition for each iteration.  The last solution listed above is equivalent to:

```
{
    char ch;
    while (std::cin.get(ch))
        ...
}
```